# how do i solve this problem while installing emulator

Tags: android-studio

when i am trying to install emulator on my mac m1 :
All packages are not available for download!The following packages are not available:-&NBSP;Package id emulator
please help

Comment: Just got a new Mac and hit this on a fresh install. Might be because I don't have Rosetta installed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.